# React Context - why is initial value always undefined for 1 property while not for other values?

Tags: reactjs, reduce, react-context

Im using react context (not redux).When I put an initial value in my reducer function, every value I pass is fine except 1 which is my notifications array. I pass empty array but initial value is always undefined. I just dont get what is different in 'notifications' vs any other value

```
const NotificationContext = createContext();

const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'fetch_notifications':
            return {
                ...state, notifications: action.payload.messages
            }
        case 'try':
            return {
                ...state, test: action.payload
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export const NotificationsProvider = ({children}) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {notifications: [], test: "test",)

const tryme = () => {
   dispatch({type: 'try', payload: "tryingme"})
}

const fetchNotifications = async () => {
    const notifications = await API.fetchNotifications();
    dispatch({type: 'fetch_notifications', payload: notifications})
};
return (
        <NotificationContext.Provider
            value={{
            state,
                fetchNotifications,
                tryme
            }}
            >
            {children}
        </NotificationContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Comment: I don't see any empty array in your code

Comment: sorry i forgot to add it, just edited my question

Comment: Are you sure that you don't run `fetchNotifications` or `tryme` before checkingif the value exists?

Comment: oh you right, i mixed up something and i actually was running before where i was checking. Anyways, thank you!